# Adding to the front of an Ordered Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I created an Ordered Linked List consisting of Nodes which contain pointers, data, and the keys used to sort them. So far in my method named "add" I have got it to successfully add after a node continually. For example, adding A then B then C. But When I try to continually add in front of a node the first node doesn't seem to have anything pointing to it or the order is incorrect. 
  By process of elimination it looks like the second else in the add method is where I am incorrectly pointing my nodes. How can I get the add method to add D then C then B which would then be ordered BCD?

```
    public class OrderedLinkedList<E>{

private int size;

private int index;

private KeyedNode currentNode;

private KeyedNode previousNode;

private KeyedNode head;

/**
 * Constructor that creates the head node that points to null and initializes size to 0.
 */
public OrderedLinkedList(){
    head = null;
    this.size = 0;
}
/**
 * Method that goes through the OrderedLinkedList and adds one to counter then returns counter as the size.
 * 
 * @return Returns the int variable counter.
 */
public int size(){    
    return this.size;
}
/**
 * 
 * @param key
 * @param value
 * @return
 */
public E add(String key, E value){
    if(currentNode == null){//takes care of empty list
        currentNode  = new KeyedNode(key, value);
        head = currentNode;
    }
    else{
        if(key.compareToIgnoreCase(currentNode.getKey()) < 0){//add to left
            KeyedNode newNode = new KeyedNode(key, value);
            if(previousNode == null){
                previousNode = currentNode;
                newNode.setNext(currentNode);
                currentNode = newNode;
                head = currentNode;
            }
            else{   
                newNode.setNext(currentNode);
                previousNode = currentNode;
                currentNode = newNode;      
            }
        }
        else if(key.compareToIgnoreCase(currentNode.getKey()) > 0){//add to right
            KeyedNode newNode = new KeyedNode(key, value);  
            previousNode = currentNode;
            currentNode = newNode;
            currentNode.setNext(previousNode.getNext());
            previousNode.setNext(currentNode);
        }
    }
    size++;
    return null;
}
/**
 * Method that looks through the keys of the OrderedLinkedList nodes and returns the data of the node.
 * @param key The String key parameter used to search the OrderedLinkedList.
 * @return Returns the data of the node with the matching key.
 */
public E find(String key){
    KeyedNode current = head;
    while(current != null){
        if(current.getKey().compareToIgnoreCase(key) == 0){
            return current.getData();
        }
        else if(key.compareToIgnoreCase(current.getKey()) < 0){
            return null;
        }
        else{
            current = current.getNext();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
/**
 * Method that creates an index for the OrderedLinkedList, then uses the index to find the position of a node to return.
 *  
 * @param position Position is an int variable used to match with index to find a node.
 * @return Returns the data of the node in the desired position.
 */
public E get(int position){
    KeyedNode current = head;
    index = 0;
    if(position < 0 || position > size){
        return null;
    }
    while(current != null){
        if(index == position){
            return current.getData();
        }
        else{
            current = current.getNext();
            index++;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
/**
 * Private inner class  KeyedNode of OrderedLinkedList begins.   
 */
private class KeyedNode{

    private String key;

    private E data;

    private KeyedNode next;

    public  KeyedNode(String keyWord, E dataItem){
        data = dataItem;
        key = keyWord;
        next = null;
    }
    //getters
    public E getData(){
        return data;
    }

    public KeyedNode getNext(){
        return next;
    }

    public String getKey(){
        return key;
    }
    //setters
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setData(E nodeData){
        data = nodeData;
    }

    public void setNext(KeyedNode nodeNext){
        next = nodeNext;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "The nodes key is: " + key;
    }
}
/**
 * private class KeyedNode ends   
 */
```

}

Comment: Why are `previousNode` and `currentNode` members of the class instead of local variable in the methods that need them? Also you don't handle the case where keys are equal. you have `if list is null else if compare < 0 else if compare > 0` what if compare == 0?

Comment: You need a `while` loop.

Comment: Consider a different name; "ordered" doesn't mean what you think it does.  Lists of all types are already ordered by definition.